# Simulate Real Car Rotation In Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a 3D racecar, car moves left and right, but it does not rotate as a real car rotates.
below is my script:

```
public class movement : MonoBehaviour {
     Rigidbody rb;
    public float forwardforce = 600f;
    public float sidwayforce;
    float left_right;
     public float thrust;
    public float speed;
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
       rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardforce *Time.deltaTime);
  Controll ();
        left_right = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

            // rb.AddForce(sidwayforce* left_right * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0,ForceMode.VelocityChange);
       // rb.AddForce( sidwayforce*left_right * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        //rb.velocity = new Vector3(sidwayforce*left_right * Time.deltaTime,0,0); 
    }
```

here is the code for moving left and right, but I want to create car rotation

```
    void Controll (){
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") > 0) {
            rb.AddForce (20f, 0, 0);
        } else {
            if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") <0) {
                rb.AddForce (-20f, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want realistic car movement, what I would suggest using is the wheel colliders. Wheel colliders can be used for both controlling acceleration/deceleration as well as turning and as such they will create more realistic car movement (so long as you set the wheel properties correctly, they can be a bit finicky).

If you follow these links, they will explain in much greater detail how wheel colliders work and how you can program them

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WheelColliderTutorial.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-WheelCollider.html